# Can the ghosting effect due to high speed be solved?

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics

There is this nasty ghosting? effect when moving an object at "high" speed over and html canvas.

Is this is normal at high speeds due to lower and lower fps per speed?
Is there a term for this in graphics?
Is this a JS thing?
Can it be solved?

(use wasd to move)
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eVNmmm

```
function drawPlayerAtPosition(pos) {
  ctx.arc(pos.x, pos.y, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2)
  ctx.fill()
}

const playerPos = new Point(centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y)
const playerVelocity = new Point(0, 0)
const playerSpeed = 5
requestAnimationFrame(animate)


function animate() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight)
  ctx.beginPath()

  movePlayer()
  drawPlayerAtPosition(playerPos)

  ctx.stroke()
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}

addEventListener('keydown', e => {

  if (e.keyCode == 87) {
    playerVelocity.y = -playerSpeed
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 83) {
    playerVelocity.y = playerSpeed
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 68) {
    playerVelocity.x = playerSpeed
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 65) {
    playerVelocity.x = -playerSpeed
  }
})

 addEventListener('keyup', e => {

  if (e.keyCode == 87) {
    playerVelocity.y = 0
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 83) {
    playerVelocity.y = 0
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 68) {
    playerVelocity.x = 0
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 65) {
    playerVelocity.x = 0
  }
})

function movePlayer() {
  playerPos.x += playerVelocity.x
  playerPos.y += playerVelocity.y
}
```

Comment: II would call it flickering. usually what helps is: Vertical sync with monitor, back buffering, cumulative motion blur effect, ... However I do not code in javascript so I do not know how to force Vertical sync, or back/double buffering... Some older LCDs got nasty postprocessing emphasizing such effects a lot If the case usually playing with OSD settings like sharpness and smoothness make a huge impact

Comment: Perfect vsync isn't possible but you can get close with a rendering loop that uses requestAnimationFrame()

Comment: @Mr Smith. well this is what I did

Comment: That you did, the typical options to deal with this problem is get more frames (Not applicable here). What I'd recommend is slowing down your moving entity a bit and apply some cross frame blur. An easy approach is to record the player's position from the last three frames and draw them at different transparancies to create a blur effect. A more complex solution would be to use an angled gaussian blur.

Comment: thanks a lot. that sounds very helpful